# what to do about squeaky floors

Tags: floor, squeak

I tore out all the old flooring upstairs of my split foyer home and need to know how I can stop the squeaking of the subfloor before I have the new flooring put down. Obviously the squeak wasn't in the old flooring. Subfloors are all that's left. There are several places that squeak pretty bad, one in the living room and one in a bedroom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the difficulty in stopping floor squeaks comes from the fact that people don't want to remove or damage their flooring to fix it.  There are special screws with heads that snap off and other gadgets to make it easy.

You have no flooring, so it makes it a lot easier.  Get some good, strong screws and go to town on the areas that squeak.  Screw the sub-floor solidly into the floor joists underneath until all movement and squeaking have stopped.  Also, walk around the area with heavy steps to try and see any additional movement that might not be squeaking yet.  Screw down anything that even feels like it might have moved.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a certain type of screw that would be best?

Comment: A good quality wood screw would be best.  They have screws made for sub floors, but if you can't find anything else a deck screw would be fine.  Don't use drywall screws - they are relatively weak.